# Error on printing our Images on Receipt via POS system

Tags: flutter, pos

Here is my code below.

```
 Future<List<int>> getImage() async {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    CapabilityProfile profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
    final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm80, profile);

    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/logo.png');
    final buffer = data.buffer;
    final image = base64.encode(Uint8List.view(buffer));
    bytes += generator.image(image);

    return bytes;
  }
```

At

```
bytes += generator.image(image);
```

the error said that

> Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image'.

Comment: base64 is a string

Comment: @flaxon, any idea how should i Fix it?

Answer (score 0):

from [The docs](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils)

you need to pass the bytes not the base64

it looks like you miss `decodeImage()`

```
Future<List<int>> getImage() async {
    List<int> bytes = [];
    CapabilityProfile profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
    final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm80, profile);

    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/logo.png');
    final Uint8List buffer = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    final Image image = decodeImage(buffer);

    bytes += generator.image(image);

    return bytes;
  }
```

Comment: final Uint8List bytes= data.buffer.asUint8List(); ,
Error: 'bytes' is already declared in this scope.

Comment: ok so use a another variable name. i changed to `buffer`

Comment: i missed your `List<int> bytes = [];`, but i think its not nodeed

Comment: 1 more issues is the final Image image, 
The name 'Image' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart' and 'package:image/src/image.dart (via package:image/image.dart)'.

Comment: add `import 'package:image/image.dart'; on top
`

Comment: hi dude im able to print it out now, but have another issues, I had posted images above

Comment: where did you posted?. please mark my answer, if i solved your problem you asked.